# Bread board for STM32

Tags: electrical-engineering, embedded-systems

I have a microcontroller similar to the one in the accompanying picture. I do not want to solder wires to the microcontroller contacts

Is it some kind of printed circuit board on which a microcontroller can be placed without having to solder wires? I cannot find anything.

[image]

Comment: It's not clear what the question is.  You mention you don't want to solder wires, but that has nothing to do with the question you actually ask, which seems to be about this board you are showing a picture of.  Closing this mess.  By the way, the microcontroller, and a lot of other circuitry, is already on that board.  You don't need to "place" the micro anywhere.  That's already been done.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the image I believe that the GPIO pins are already mapped to 0.1" (2.54mm) male connector pins. If my assumption is correct you have few options

1. Use 0.100" (2.54 mm) Female Header such as one one below. Then you can solder the male pin on the female header.

[image: 0.100" (2.54 mm) Female Header]

2. Use Male/Female Jumper Wires like the ones below

[image: Male/Female Jumper Wires]

Using the above you should be able route the signal to an external PCB.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to solder wires to the microcontroller contacts looking into STM32 expansion boards. They look something like the following:

[image: STM32F4 Discovery Shield]

The above one is called STM32 discovery shield. You can attach other peripherals can create a development board like the following

[image]

Below are some links to find other alternative solutions

References:

- [STM32F4 Discovery Shield](http://www.mikroe.com/stm32/stm32f4-discovery-shield/)
- [Impressive Dev Boards for your STM32 Dev board](http://hackaday.com/2013/02/19/impressive-dev-boards-for-your-stm32-dev-boards/)
- [STM32F4DISCOVERY extension board](http://www.st.com/content/st_com/en/products/evaluation-tools/product-evaluation-tools/mcu-eval-tools/stm32-mcu-eval-tools/stm32-3rd-party-evaluation-tools/stm32f4dis-ext.html)